# Spring batch- spring batch reading from 1 table and it's child tables write different records

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch.
My project is to write the data into file with below structure

Header------------------------

Invoice

List Orders in invoices

More details of order

Footer for each invoice.

File footer.

In my case for each inv, fetch the orders in that invoice and then fetch additional details of the order from other table. The count of orders under invoice can be more 400k.

So I am confused of how to create steps which would create the file.
Pls assist thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a custom reader that reads one order with its details as a logical item. The aggregate order type is the item type that should be used in the step.

You might need a custom writer as well to output the order in different lines.